# removing trailing words end with : from a string using perl

Tags: perl

i have question on how to remove specific set of words that end with : in a string using perl.

For instance,

```
lunch_at_home: start at 1pm.
```

I want to get only "start at 1 pm"after discarding "lunch_at_home:"

note that lunch_at_home is just an example. It can be any string with any length  but it should end with ":"

Comment: [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job.

```
my $string = "lunch_at_home: start at 1pm." 
$string =~ s/^.*:\s*//;
```

It will remove all char before `:` including the `:`

Comment: @BrianKintz maybe. I have changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a specific set of words that are set apart from the data you want:

```
my $string = 'lunch_at_home: start at 1pm.';
$string =~ s/\b(lunch_at_home|breakfast_at_work):\s*//;
```

That would leave you with `start at 1pm.` and you can expand the list as needed.

If you just want to remove any "words" (we'll use the term loosely) that end with a colon:

```
my $string = 'lunch_at_home: start at 1pm.';
$string =~ s/\b\S+:\s*//;
```

You'd end up with the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

take

```
my $string = "lunch_at_home: start at 1pm.";
```

to remove everything up to the last ":" and the period at the end of the entry as in your question:

```
$string =~ s/.*: (.*)\./$1/;
```

to remove everything up to the first ":"

```
$string =~ s/.*?: (.*)\./$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on `:` and discard the first part:

```
my (undef, $value) = split /:\s*/, $string, 2;
```

The final argument (`2`), ensures this works correctly if the trailing string contains a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function to achieve this:

```
my $string = "lunch_at_home: start at 1pm.";
$string = (split /:\s*/, $string)[1];
print "$string\n";
```